# How do i calculate the area of a figure that can't be projected in XY?

Tags: calculus

i am just confused because i realized that i can't calcualte the area of figures that aren't projected in the XY plane. In another words, to calcualte the area of a curve (actualy, the region bounded by the curve), i would need to rotate to another coordinate system that makes it possible to project the curve in the xy plane, but this is a little troublesome.

For example, suppose we need to calculate the area of the intersection of a plane inclined wrt to xy with a cone. That is, of an ellipse [image]

What formula could i use to calculate the area of the region bounded by the yellow curve belonging to the blue plane, if i don't want to transform to another coordinate system?
Of course $\int dxdy$ can't be used here, the z variable is also important after all.

Comment: You are fortunate here because the figure belongs to a plane. If the angle between the plane and the (horizontal) plane on which you project it is $\alpha$, just use formula $A_{proj.}=A_{initial} \times \cos \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is the angle between the 2 planes.

Comment: When you say "can't be projected in the XY plane", do you actually mean, "does not lie in a plane parallel to the $x,y$ plane"? Because if the base of the cone in your figure lies in the $x,y$ plane you certainly **can** project the ellipse onto the $x,y$ plane. It will just get changed in shape and size when you do so, but the previous comment explains exactly how the size changes.

Comment: @DavidK Yes this is exactly what i means, that it does not lie parallel to XY

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you can parameterize the surface, you can use a surface area integral: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/integrating-multivariable-functions/surface-integrals-articles/a/surface-area-integrals

Note that the region that is being integrated over ($T$ in the article) doesn't have to be a rectangle. For your ellipse example, if you can figure out the projection of the ellipse onto the $xy$-plane, you can parameterize it as $(x,y,f(x,y))$ for $x,y$ in that projection, and $f$ the height of the plane.